# Chrome Extension - How to paste value at option page field of B extension from A extension with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing Chrome Extension. And that extension create values by user's control. And I want to paste that values to fields of option page of other Chrome Extension.

```
Chrome Extension A and B.
A: User create values
A -> B: Paste values to B from A (User control is on A)
```

Can I control other extension from my extension and automate that?

Comment: You can register a devtools panel using chrome.devtools API, so while devtools is open on another extension's page your panel script will be able to access it. Study the existing extensions for guidance e.g. Storage Area Explorer.

Comment: I found some documentation that might help: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external

Comment: Thanks all. I will try chrome.devtools and message communication.